# Are nested structured bindings possible?

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

Assume I have an object of type

```
std::map<std::string, std::tuple<int, float>> data;
```

Is it possible to access the element types in a nested way (i.e. when used in ranged for loop) like this

```
for (auto [str, [my_int, my_float]] : data) /* do something */
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I tried it. It doesn't work with the syntax above. Thats why I'm asking if it is even possible.

Comment: A problem is: how to tell C++ what const/reference-ness to use for each hidden object to which each nested set of introduced names are bound? The const/reference qualifier refers to said hidden object, not the introduced aliases to its members/`get()`. I can't see how it'd matter in this case if both were the same, nor immediately think of cases where distinct qualifiers would be needed, but I wouldn't want C++ to add in nested structured bindings if they were 2nd-class compared to what we currently have. And making them 1st-class seems perilous, when the grammar is probably already straining!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

I distinctly remember reading somewhere that nested structured bindings are not allowed for C++17, but they are considering allowing it in a future standard. Can't find the source though.

Comment: I'm curious how the syntax will not clash with attributes if nested decompositions become a thing.

Comment: Sad. That would have been one step closer to Python++. @miradulo I was asking the same question to myself. Are attributes even allowed after a type qualifier like `auto [[attribute]] [var1, var2]`?

Comment: @Timo Yup, take a look at the [cppref example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes). Attributes can be almost anywhere.

Comment: @miradulo Maybe extra tailing comma? Like auto [[a,b],] = func();

Answer (score 33):

No, they aren't possible; but this is:

```
for (auto&& [key, value] : data) {
  auto&& [my_int, my_float] = value;
}
```

which is close at least.

Comment: Yes that's how I'm doing it now. Thanks.

Comment: (Just out of curiosity for something I didn't understand 100% yet:) What is the benefit of using universal refs here? Aren't `data` and `value` l-values, so that these universal refs will result in being l-value refs in the end anyway?

Comment: @kaba I am lazy, and use either `auto&&` if I don't care, `auto const&` when I want to block modification, `auto&` when I want to modify what I'm iterating over, and `auto` when I want a copy I can modify and not impact the original sequence.  Here, I don't care, so I use `auto&&`; `auto&&` to me means "I do not care how this is stored -- alias or copy or whatever".

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in C++20

```
for (auto& [my_int, my_float] : data | std::views::values)
{
    // Some code
}
```