# how to iterate over "enumerated zip" of 2 containers in C++23?

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

how to iterate over "enumerated zip" of 2 containers in C++23?
in Python, i would write something like:

```py
A = [10, 20, 30]
B = [40, 50, 60]
for (i, (a, b)) in enumerate(zip(A, B)):
  print(i, a, b)
```

which sequentially outputs index `i` and corresponding elements from `A` and `B`.

in C++23 `enumerate` and `zip` equivalents exist (`<ranges>`), but i cannot figure out how to combine them properly.

```cpp
  using namespace std;
  
  auto A = vector {10, 20, 30};
  auto B = vector {40, 50, 60};
  
  // zip
  for (auto [a, b]: views::zip(A, B))
    cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
  
  // enumerate
  for (auto [i, a]: views::enumerate(A))
    cout << i << " " << a << "\n";

  // zip and enumerate? nope. does not compile:
  for (auto [i, [a, b]]: views::enumerate(views::zip(A, B)))
    cout << i << " " << a << " " << b << "\n";
```

the first error on the first square bracket in `[i, [a, b]]` is:

Type 'std::ranges::enumerate_viewstd::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>, std::ranges::ref_viewstd::vector<int>>>::_Iterator::__reference_type' (aka 'tuple<long, std::pair<int &, int &>>') decomposes into 2 elements, but only 1 name was provided selected 'begin' function with iterator type '_Iterator'

and the second error on the second square bracket: Expected identifier

Comment: [Nested structured bindings are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49035732/are-nested-structured-bindings-possible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [std::views::iota](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view) to make the indices:

```
for (auto [i, a, b]: std::views::zip(std::views::iota(0), A, B)) {
    std::cout << i << " " << a << " " << b << "\n";
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MWa9v1Y33)

Note that the zip-and-enumerate way does work if you are willing to then unpack the vector values (with `std::get` or another structured binding for example):

```
for (auto [i, v]: std::views::enumerate(std::views::zip(A, B))) {
    std::cout << i << " " << std::get<0>(v) << " " << std::get<1>(v) << "\n";
    //
    // or
    //
    // std::cout << i << " " << v.first << " " << v.second << "\n";
    //
    // or
    //
    // auto [a, b] = v;
    // std::cout << i << " " << a << " " << b << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Structured bindings don't support nested bindings yet. Hopefully at some point. That's why this doesn't work:

```cpp
for (auto [i, [a, b]]: views::enumerate(views::zip(A, B)))
```

For the same reason that this non-ranges example doesn't work either:

```cpp
auto [i, [a, b]] = std::pair(1, std::pair(2, 3));
```

So you would have to do it this, admittedly tedious, way:

```cpp
for (auto [i, ab] : views::enumerate(views::zip(A, B))) {
    auto [a, b] = ab;
    // ...
}
```

In a simple for loop, just doing `views::zip(views::iota(0), A, B)` is fine (as suggested in the other answer), but note that in other algorithm usage, `enumerate(x)` can be a common+sized range if `x` is, whereas `zip(iota(0), x)` won't be either common or sized - which may matter.